# In simple terms, why does the tunnel diode oscillate in this circuit?

Tags: diodes, oscillator, oscillation

Why does the tunnel diode current in [this](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/sinusoidal_oscillators/sinusoidal_tunnel_diode_oscillator.htm) circuit oscillate over time? I had trouble understanding the given explanation.

[image]

Specifically, why doesn't the voltage across the tunnel diode rise to a steady state and then dictate the current through the diode based on the V-I curve?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> *In Simple Terms, Why does the Tunnel Diode Oscillate in This Circuit?*

In simple terms because a tunnel diode's voltage-current characteristic has a region of negative resistance. And, you can make a "theoretical oscillator using a -10 kΩ resistor and a tuned circuit like this: -

[image]

Simulation proof: -

[image]

Here I'm using back-to-back diodes to limit the amplitude of the sinewave. It's all down to negative resistance: -

[image]

Image from [OP's link](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/sinusoidal_oscillators/sinusoidal_tunnel_diode_oscillator.htm). Between A and B there is negative resistance; as voltage increases, current falls.